# <ng-template></ng-template> is loading multiple times

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-template, angular5, ng-template

I am using ngTemplateOutlet to load . but It loads a template multiple times .It is loading correct template but it executing multiple times loadTemplate() method.

In **HTML**:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="loadTemplate()"></ng-template>
    </tbody>
</table>

<ng-template #template1>
    <tr *ngFor="iteration">
        <p>Hiii</p>
    </tr>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template2>
    <tr *ngFor="iteration">
        <p>Byee</p>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

In my **component.ts**:

```
@ViewChild('template1') template1: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('template1') template1: TemplateRef<any>;
loadTemplate(){
    if (condition)
        return this.template1;

    return this.template2;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[ngTemplateOutlet]="loadTemplate()"
```

causes `loadTemplate()` to be called every time change detection runs.

Rather assign the result of `loadTemplate()` to a field and use that field in binding

```
[ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate"
```

then change detection and the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive can see that there was no change and won't re-initialize the template.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="condition ? template1 : template2"></ng-template>
    </tbody>
</table>

<ng-template #template1>
    <tr *ngFor="iteration">
        <p>Hiii</p>
    </tr>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template2>
    <tr *ngFor="iteration">
        <p>Byee</p>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```